# Failed to execute Git Fatal: The current branch (Ticket# - Action ) has no upstream branch

Tags: github, bitbucket, vscode-extensions, pull-request

The problem:

Hello,

I am using vscode with bitbucket that contains my repos.

I can create a new branch.

I can make my changes and save the commits.

When I go to generate the pull request in vscode I am promtped the error "Failed to execute Git Fatal: The current branch (Ticket# - Action ) has no upstream branch."  I was able to create PR earlier. Just under this branch it does not want to work.

I deleted the initial pull request.

Created a new PR same result

I deleted the repo from my PC and recloned it via https

It successfully resintalled the repo to my computer.

I also performed a git -init and it successfully reinitialized the existing repo on my computer.

I also went as far as uninstalling the plugin installed on vscode and reinstalled it.

When attempting to create the pull request it still occurs.

The Path of where the repo resides in my pc is C:/Users/user.profile/Documents/BitBucket/TerraForm/tenant_data/ ( it has a .git folder within )

I am new to git, bitbucket, and vscode.

Expectation:

Curious as to what stopped working as it work for a while and now its been two days since ive been unable to create pull requests.

I don't have a means of reaching bitbucket support or vscode support on this.

I am hoping to get some steps to try and resolve this.

Where I can create a branch.

Generate a pull request from bitbucket in vscode.

Answer (score 0):

Appears an update to the extension has changed the sequence I use to follow.

I learned that if I use terminal and perform the following.

Enter the command `git checkout -b <branch_name>` to create a new branch and switch to it.

Use the command `git branch` to confirm that you are in the correct branch.

Make the necessary changes to the code in the branch.

For example, I can edit a file like test.json.

Use the command `git add <relative path of the file>` to stage the changes I made to the file.

Use the command `git commit -m "commit comment goes here"` to commit the changes I made to the file with a descriptive commit message.

Use the command `git push --set-upstream origin <branch_name>` to push the changes to the remote repository and set the upstream branch.

My sequence before this was all done by creating a branch, switching to branch from master, making changes, saving the change, committing the change, generate PR within the extension.

Somehow my local branch would not reach the remote server in this. if I use the git commands it works.